# Python: How can I override one module in a package with a modified version that lives outside the package?

Tags: python, django

I would like to update one module in a python package with my own version of the module, with the following conditions:

- I want my updated module to live outside of the original package (either because I don't have access to the package source, or because I want to keep my local modifications in a separate repo, etc).
- I want `import` statements that refer to original package/module to resolve to my local module

Here's an example of what I'd like to do using specifics from django, because that's where this problem has arisen for me:

Say this is my project structure

```
django/
  ... the original, unadulterated django package ...
local_django/
  conf/
    settings.py
myproject/
  __init__.py
  myapp/
    myfile.py
```

And then in myfile.py

```
# These imports should fetch modules from the original django package
from django import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

# I would like this following import statement to grab a custom version of settings 
# that I define in local_django/conf/settings.py 
from django.conf import settings

def foo():
  return settings.some_setting
```

Can I do some magic with the `__import__` statement in `myproject/__init__.py` to accomplish this? Is there a more "pythonic" way to achieve this?

### Update - Why do I want to do this

Here's the scenario where I think this makes sense.

- I am launching a django powered website on a server that has django pre-installed globally. I can't modify the actual django source, in this case.
- My django project uses 3rd party reusable apps, and I don't want to change `imports` in all of those apps to import, for instance `mycustomsettings`. I want to leave the reusable apps blissfully ignorant that I have changed the implementation of django.conf.settings.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just set the entry in sys.modules before anything else imports it:

```
import sys
import myreplacement
sys.modules["original"] = myreplacement
```

Then, when someone does "import original", they'll get your version instead.

If you want to replace a submodule, you can do it like this:

```
import sys
import thepackage
sys.modules["thepackage"].submodule = myreplacement
sys.modules["thepackage.submodule"] = myreplacement
```

Then "from thepackage import submodule" or "import thepackage.submodule" will give "myreplacement".

Comment: With this approach, could I override a module within a package? I want `import foo.bar.somemodule` to load my version of somemodule.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can make use of the [django-values](http://code.google.com/p/django-values/) project, which provides a `dbsettings` app, which ...

> ... allows placeholders for settings to be
>   defined in Python, while their values
>   are set by staff using an editor while
>   the server is up and running. Many
>   value types are available, and they
>   each map to a native Python type, so
>   model methods and other Python code
>   can access them as standard class
>   attributes.
>
> Much effort has also been made to
>   reduce the overhead of this feature,
>   so that the database is only queried
>   once during each server restart, and
>   only updated when the values
>   themselves are updated.
>
> NOTE: This is not intended as a
>   replacement for settings.py. This is
>   designed for values that are expected
>   to change based on the needs of the
>   site or its users, so that such
>   changes don't require so much as a
>   restart. settings.py is still the
>   place to go for settings that will
>   only vary by project.
>
> One way of looking at it is that
>   settings.py is for those things that
>   are required from a technical
>   perspective (database connections,
>   installed applications, avaialble
>   middleware, etc), while dbsettings is
>   best for those things that are
>   required due to organizational policy
>   (quotas, minimum requirements, etc).
>   That way, programmers maintain the
>   technical requirements, while
>   administrators maintain organizational
>   policy.

The project is by Marty Alchin (who wrote the Pro Django book) and does not require any changes to Django code - it's a standard Django application.

Comment: django-values is nice. I've used it before. But I'm really not looking for a solution specific to django settings. I just included that as an example. I'm hoping to get some insight on if this is possible through pythons import.

Answer (score 1):

```
import local_django.conf
import django.conf
django.conf.settings = local_django.conf.settings
```

Modules are singletons. Modules are only initialized/loaded once. You need to do this before importing the modules that use django.conf.settings for them to pick up the change.

Read this link for more info to see if there is a more standard approach with django as the docs specifically recommend against doing it the way I show above for the settings object.
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/
It should work fine for other objects and modules.

Comment: Awesome. Didn't know it was that easy. Thanks.

Comment: That example using django.conf.settings is an inappropriate example as django uses getters and setters to automatically override the global settings with the local ones. The django docs specifically say not to do what I did in that example because the local settings automatically override the global settings. Watch out for side effects if you use the above method for that specific settings object in django.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, 'twould be best to follow the prescribed [mechanism for creating your own settings](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#creating-your-own-settings).

In the general case, mucking with imports is guaranteed to confuse your reader (who may be you). The pythonic way to alter class behavior is to sub-class and override.

Comment: Thanks msw. But I don't want to create my own settings, I want to change the django's core behavior around settings, by, e.g., storing some settings in the database and making them editable through the admin. I added some of this rationale to the question to clarify.

Comment: And I do want to sub-class and override, but I want to do it in a file that lives outside of the original package directory structure

Answer (score 0):

I was introduced to this about two or three days ago, but one technique of doing this very thing is to use a Python Virtual Environment.  This allows you to designate the version of Python you are using, as well as the versions of the modules you want to install, and to be able to swap between different versions and projects relatively easy; it also allows you to install a Python system where you might not otherwise have the permissions needed to install something.

You can learn more about virtualenv from [virtualenv info](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).

There's also a "virtualenvwrapper" package, that provides tools to more easily swap between environments.

Admittedly, I don't have much experience with this, and I found this question in an attempt to understand how to override a Python Standard Library with a custom-built version--so it's not perfect.  But I am nonetheless impressed with its ability to specify what you install, down to the version of an individual module!